# Pass hidden data through XUL autocomplete textbox?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

One of the controls needed in my xulrunner application is an autocompleting text box which allows the user to type a search term, then looks up completions in an array of objects (each having a generated UUID, canonical name, a list of search terms gleaned from related data, etc.) and allows the user to select just one.  Currently I'm using a textbox element of type="autocomplete" and a Javascript custom search component, and it is successfully prefix searching all the search terms and providing completions below the text field, in the customary fashion.

The catch is that I'm not interested in the possibly non-unique label but the object from which the label came, and I can't see any way of passing the object or even any out-of-band UUID back into document land without modifying the XBL or rolling my own control from scratch.  Essentially I'm seeking to do what could have been done in HTML with the option[value] attribute.  I can't use the built-in type-to-search effect of a standalone menulist because I need to prefix search multiple fields of the object.  Any recommendations?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own as a listbox inside a panel next to a textbox.  Even composed into an XBL binding, this was less effort than I'd spent working with the built-in autocomplete textbox and trying to force it to handle what it wasn't intended to handle.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark you answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~